# Which jars do I need in order to avoid "NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler"?

Tags: jsf, facelets, myfaces

I'm trying to build a JavaServer Faces 2.0 project (using Apache Myfaces 2.0.2 + Tomcat 7.0.25 via Eclipse Indigo). All seems to be set, Tomcat starts ok, but when I try to open a web page I get the error:

> SEVERE: An exception occurred 
>   javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler

As I understand, some jar(s) are missing, the one which has this class: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.

Jar finder tells me that I should have "jsf-facelets.jar" (http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler/).

However, there is no download section at http://facelets.java.net/.

Which jars do I need? Why isn't MyFaces enough?

```
INFO: Server startup in 20457 ms
10.02.2012. 15:51:03 org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter handleThrowable
SEVERE: An exception occurred
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2836)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.classForName(ClassUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.util.ReflectionUtil.forName(ReflectionUtil.java:67)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:475)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement(TagLibraryConfig.java:373)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:632)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compileViewMetadata(Compiler.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:311)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1902)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.access$000(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage$FaceletViewMetadata.createMetadataView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2136)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Are you using RichFaces 3.x instead of 4.x or so? What JARs do you all have in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: I'm using Myfaces 2.0.2.
Jars are: 
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-discovery-0.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
myfaces-api-2.0.2.jar
myfaces-impl-2.0.2.jar
And also JSTL jars:
jstl-api-1.2.jar
jstl-impl-1.2.jar

Comment: Looks fine. Didn't you have manually put anything in Tomcat/lib or even JRE/lib or JRE/lib/ext?

Comment: I also have Tomahawk jars and AXIS2 jars. But should they matter?

Comment: Which jar contains com.sun.facelets?

Comment: Tomahawk and AXIS2 don't have Facelets 1.x dependencies. Facelets 1.x is contained in `jsf-facelets.jar`, but you should **not** need to have it if you're using JSF 2.x, unless you're using for example RichFaces 3.x on JSF 2.x (which requires more hacks anyway). Can you please edit your question to include the full stacktrace? Perhaps it contains information about what dependency is requiring Facelets 1.x.

Comment: OK, you are already helping me. 

The project, in fact, used to be JSF 1.x, and now I am converting it to JSF 2, so there must be some code left that is using 1.x. Is that the right direction?

Comment: Updated the question with stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I was using Tomahawk for JSF 1.2 instead of Tomahawk for JSF 2.0 while I was using JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Relevant part from the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
    ...
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:475)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement(TagLibraryConfig.java:373)
```

There's somewhere a Facelets 1.x tag library in your webapp and I think it's a custom one as you don't seem to be using JSF 1.x targeted component libraries (such as RichFaces 3.x or Tomahawk for JSF 1.x). Look for `*.taglib.xml` files in your webapp (they're usually in `/WEB-INF` or `/META-INF`) and update its XML root declaration to comply Facelets 2.0 as follows:

```xml
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Comment: No, don't have any xmls like *.taglib.xml.

Comment: Then it's in one of the JARs in the classpath. You have still not answered my question in the comment if you have ever touched Tomcat's or JRE's library. You've got to post a list of **all** JARs you have manually placed in the *entire* runtime classpath so that one can point out the offending JAR.

Comment: No, I did not add anything to Tomcat/lib, nor JRE/lib. Where else should I look?

Comment: Which tag libraries have you all imported in your view? In other words, show all XML namespaces you've declared in your view root.

Comment: Seems like Tomahawk was the problem. I was removing jars package by package, and when I removed Tomahawk it stoped giving me that error. Now I went to http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html and I see there are separate versions for JSF 1.2 and 2.0. So, could we say Tomahawk needs to be upgraded?

Comment: So you were using Tomahawk for JSF 1.2 instead of Tomahawk for JSF 2.0 while you're using JSF 2.0? Well, that's definitely the problem!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am new to this. It was a JSF 1.2 project, and now I am converting it step by step to JSF 2.0. Thanks for all the help.