# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler after upgrading from MyFaces 1.1 to MyFaces 2.2

Tags: maven, jsf-2.2, myfaces, tomahawk

I am trying to migrate a web application from MyFaces 1.1 to 2.2.

I basically followed the first steps under **Basic Changes** from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532870/5467214 to upgrade from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.2:

- update `web.xml`
- update `faces-config.xml`
- replace old `myfaces` jars with version 2.2 jars

For the time being, I intend to keep JSP and replace them with Facelets once the first, presumably "painless" steps of *just* upgrading JSF are successful.

The web application worked with the old JSF version but after doing the steps described above, I get the following error and stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1191)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.ClassUtils.classForName(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.util.ReflectionUtil.forName(ReflectionUtil.java:66)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.createClass(TagLibraryConfig.java:539)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:466)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.FaceletsCompilerSupport.loadLibraries(FaceletsCompilerSupport.java:157)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.loadLibraries(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2526)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createCompiler(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2172)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.initialize(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2464)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.<init>(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguageStrategy.java:52)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.initialize(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.createView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:255)
    at org.jenia.faces.template.handler.ViewHandler.createView(ViewHandler.java:251)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.createView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.createView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:70)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:289)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 54 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jsfcomp.chartcreator.ChartListener.afterPhase(ChartListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersAfter(PhaseListenerManager.java:117)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:211)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We use Tomcat7 as a servlet container, IntelliJ Community Edition as IDE and Maven as a build manager and for dependency management.

Since "Tomahawk" appears in the stack trace, I replaced `tomahawk-1.1.9.jar` with `tomahawk21-1.1.14.jar` in my `/WEB-INF/lib`, according to [Which jars do I need in order to avoid "NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/tag/jsf/ComponentHandler"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228935/which-jars-do-i-need-in-order-to-avoid-noclassdeffounderror-com-sun-facelets-t). Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.

I also couldn't find a tomahawk version specifically for JSF 2.2, neither in the maven repository nor anywhere else.

Would that be necessary to use tomahawk with MyFaces 2.2?

Or does the error stem from something else?

Comment: Are you **sure** tomahawk-1.x  is not still there somewhere? And check this: `at org.jenia.faces.template.handler.ViewHandler.createView(ViewHandler.java:251)`... jenia??? And `net.sf.jsfcomp.chartcreator.`?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your response. Yes, I just verified that there is no other tomahawk library in the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory apart from `tomahawk21-1.1.14.jar`. I don't know what this `jenia` taglib is - the joys of inheriting ancient code with the task to update it - but when I remove it I get an error when trying to deploy the webapp on the Tomcat servlet container.

Comment: The Jenia "dynamic" library that we apparently use comes from http://www.jenia.org/, and the only two tags that we use from that library are `jp:popupFrame` and `jp:closePopupFrame`. Judging by https://sourceforge.net/p/jenia4faces/bugs/48/, I guess there is no JSF2 compatible version of the library. So I will try to remove all usages of these tags, remove the taglib and see if it works. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Kukeltje The `jenia` library was indeed the culprit! After removing it, the error vanished. Thanks again for pointing it out!

Comment: Soo easy to find if you read the stacktrace... Would have saved you a lot of time posting a question and us time too!!! Please learn from this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace, I suspect another JSF 1.x specific library causes this:

```
at org.jenia.faces.template.handler.ViewHandler.createView(ViewHandler.java:251)
```

So check what the 'jenia' library is  and get a newer jsf 2 compatible version or remove it.